# Rss feed writer for php mysql

Tags: php

hi i have the around 15 articles in my table, i want  rss feed writter script,

Refer some open source site for this..

Comment: I'd like the moon on a teak stick, but I don't suspect I'll get it without putting some effort in myself.

Comment: $newItem = $TestFeed->createNewItem();
   while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $article_id = $row['article_id'];
  $article_title = $row['article_title'];
  $article = $row['article'];
  $doc = $row['doc'];
  $dom = $row['dom'];
   $newItem->setTitle($article_title);
   $newItem->setLink(RSS_LINK."?article_id=".$article_id);
   $newItem->setDescription($article_title);
   $newItem->setDate($doc);
  
     
  } $TestFeed->addItem($newItem);

this sample snippet, the output for this , repeated rows

Comment: To post your code, add it as an answer. So it might be useful for others who want the moon on a stick.

Answer (score 0):

RSS is really simple. Check out some feeds you know to see the simple XML markup, and then see the RSS specification:

http://validator.w3.org/feed/docs/rss2.html